# Facebook SDK PHP Mutual Friends

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the mutual friends of a person from facebook.  Im using a variation of the code from the following tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcABLvN6Fmk

and trying to use the following information

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user.context/mutual_friends

Ive nearly got it working my problem is that I can't figure out how to phraze the query

here is my code

```
require "fbsdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php";
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'MY_APP_ID',
        'app_secret' => 'MY_APP_SECRET',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6'
]);

if(isset($_SESSION['user_profile']['facebook_access_token'])){
    $query = ‘/me/friends?limit=100’;

    $res = $fb->get($query, $_SESSION['user_profile']['facebook_access_token']);
    $my_friend_list = $res->getGraphEdge()->asArray();  

    echo    "my friends that use the app:<br/>";
    print_r($my_friend_list);
    echo    "<br/><br/>";

    if(isset($_SESSION['query']['user'][$current_user]['user_facebook_id'])){
        $query = 'HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO PHRAZE THIS QUERY';

        $res = $fb->get($query, $_SESSION['user_profile']['facebook_access_token']);
        $mutual_friend_list = $res->getGraphEdge()->asArray();  

        echo    "mutual friends that use the app:<br/>";
        print_r($mutual_friend_list);
        echo    "<br/><br/>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mutual friends mean that you want to know the mutual between **two** users. As given in the docs, the call is

```
GET /v2.6/{user-id}?fields=context.fields{mutual_friends}
```

where `{user-id}` is the user id you want to check the mutual friends for. The base user is derived from the User Access Token you're using with the call.

Keep in mind that both users need to have given your app the `user_friends` permission!

Comment: You are a god.  Thanks.  Im now getting a response back but i needed to do this

---- query = '{user-id}?fields=context.fields%28mutual_friends%29'; ---

now just need to decode the response

---- $mutual_friend_list = $res->getGraphEdge()->asArray();  ----

does not work.  Time to do some research.

Answer (score 0):

Success!  Thanks to Tobi i have a solution.  I have abstracted it a bit so its useful for others. Make sure you have the 5.0 SDK

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted#install-manually

```
require "fbsdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php";
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'MY_APP_ID',
    'app_secret' => 'MY_APP_SECRET',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
]);

$my_friend_list = array();
$mutual_friend_list = array();

if(isset($your_access_token)){
    $query = '/me/friends?limit=100';

    $res = $fb->get($your_access_token);
    $my_friend_list = $res->getGraphEdge()->asArray();  

    if(isset($another_user_id)){
        $query = '/'.$another_user_id.'?fields=context.fields%28mutual_friends%29';

        $res = $fb->get($your_access_token);
        $mutual_friend_list = $res->getGraphObject()->asArray();    
    }
}

//process information of $my_friend_list
//process information of $mutual_friend_list

//both of these have extra info in the array so check their structure
```